What does "has been manifested" mean in Romans 3:21?
Romans 3:21  ESV

"But now the righteousness of God has been manifested apart from the law, although the Law and the Prophets bear witness to it-". [My emphasis]

What has been manifested?
When was it manifested?
To whom was it manifested?
How was it manifested?
Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges  says:

"has been manifested" i.e. historically, "by the appearing of our Saviour Jesus Christ" 2 Timothy 1:10

My comment: Jesus came to fulfil the Law and the Prophets [Matthew 5:17] but in Romans 3:21 what was manifested was manifested "apart from the law". [choris/apart/without]
Jesus came to fulfil,  being within the boundaries of, the law, but what was manifested [Ro 3:21] was without/apart from the law.

The reader of the New Testament must be brought to an awesome appreciation of the righteousness of God in order to understand what Paul was saying here. It is not any righteousness involved in the law that is the focus; nor that of any righteousness of humanity. ("For there is no-one righteous, no, not one" Paul said in Romans 3:10, also, "by the deeds of the law there shall no flesh be justified in his sight : for by the law is the knowledge of sin." (leading into the verse in question.)
Paul had to be cast to the ground and made physically blind at a revelation of the risen Christ before he could become untangled from his legalistic view of righteousness. He had to learn, for the first time in his life, how God's righteousness was manifested to the world through what happened at Golgotha. Here's a section from a book that takes 109 pages to explain the matter, so this answer will only be a small point.

"In olden time, the law and the prophets witnessed - martria - to
its existence [the righteousness of God]. Romans 3:21. Evidently so to
anyone who reads them. Now, in Paul's gospel, it is manifested without
the law, Romans 3:21 again. Manifested - phaneroo - by preaching,
yes.
But now, also, is the righteousness of God revealed to faith. It is
revealed - apokalupto - to every one who believeth in God who
justifieth the ungodly. Inasmuch as waves cover - kalupto - a boat,
Matthew 8:24; inasmuch as mountains, falling upon men, will hide -
kalupto - them, Luke 23:30. By so much is the righteousness of God uncovered - apokalupto - out of the faith of Christ unto the faith
of the roaring, repentant, confessing sinner who hungers and thirsts
after such a justifying, divine, righteousness. ...the righteousness of
God, which, freely, by grace, is unto and upon every one who responds
by heartfelt, love-gendered faith to the glorious gospel of the
Blessed God.
The righteousness of God is a justifying righteousness... The
demonstration of this... is that it condemns the one who offered
himself up on behalf of all. This kind of righteousness is the kind
that makes him, who yielded himself up, to be sin, who knew not sin."
Righteousness, pp.101-2, Nigel Johnstone, Belmont, 2012

When God poured out his wrath upon his Son on the cross, he was judging sin righteously, for God is righteous in his Being. That was what sin deserved and required if God was to deal justly with sin. The Son willingly bore the punishment, without deserving it in his sinless self, for he became sin, so that sin be dealt with in one fell swoop from heaven. Thereafter, all sinners who repented and put faith in what Christ suffered in their stead could be justly cleared of all charges. God does not require punishment twice!
Paul explains more about the righteousness of God in chapter 1, from verse 16 to 19, which also say "that which may be known of God is manifested to them [all ungodly and unrighteous men]." Compare those verse with the same phrases in chapter 3.
The manifestation in chapter 1 is the evidence God has provided to all humanity that he is the righteous God, the creator. He has shown it. There is evidence of it all around, so that nobody will be without excuse on the Day of Judgment, who claimed it wasn't possible to be sure God existed, let alone that this is a righteous God.
The manifestation in chapter 3 is the evidence God has provided to all humanity that he righteously punished sin at Golgotha. Of course, ungodly and unrighteous people will never grasp that because they are spiritually dead and blind. They refuse to believe "the gospel of Christ [which] is the power of God unto salvation to every one that believeth" (1:16). That, however, does nothing to undermine the fact that God's righteousness has been manifested. Paul came to grasp that fact as the scales dropped from his blinded eyes, and he arose to new life in Christ. Of course, he had long believed in the righteousness of God by trying to adhere strictly to the law (even though he had to admit it only made him more aware of his own sin - Romans 7:5-24.)
Summary Answer re. Romans 3:21:
The righteousness of God has been manifested.
It was manifested at Golgotha.
It was manifested to, and testified to, the whole world.
It was manifested publicly, in the place of Jesus' execution at that particular time, once only, with eye-witnesses who then spread the news into the whole world with the gospel of Christ, how he bore the wrath of God in his own body, for sin, as sin must be punished. God has punished sin, and because he is righteous, he will not require punishment a second time. That is because the sin of all believers was punished then. Could it be any more clear than in these verses?

"Being justified freely by his grace through the redemption that is in
Christ Jesus: whom God hath set forth, propitiation through faith in
his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that
are past, through the forbearance of God. To declare at this time
his righteousness : that he might be just and the justifier of him
which believeth in Jesus. Where is boasting then? It is excluded. By
what law? of works? Nay: but by the law of faith without the
deeds of the law." Romans 3:24-28 A.V.


The answer to the OP's question about the identity, timing, people to whom the righteousness of God was manifested/revealed is answered in the very next verse following Rom 3:21 -

21 But now, apart from the law, the righteousness of God has been revealed, as attested by the Law and the Prophets. 22 And this
righteousness from God comes through faith in Jesus Christ to all who
believe. There is no distinction, 23 for all have sinned and fall
short of the glory of God, 24 and are justified freely by His
grace through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus.
25 God presented Him as the atoning sacrifice through faith in His blood, in order to demonstrate His righteousness, because in His
forbearance He had passed over the sins committed beforehand. 26
He did this to demonstrate His righteousness at the present time, so
as to be just and to justify the one who has faith in Jesus.

That is, the righteousness of God is revealed/manifested in Jesus Christ who offers the divine grace as demonstrated by His voluntary sacrifice on the cross for all humanity.  This righteousness is a gift of God and cannot be earned by works of the law as the above passage is at pains to point out.
Thus, we receive the righteousness of God by faith in Jesus.
Therefore, the righteousness of God was manifest in Jesus precisely because Jesus was revealed in the flesh during His incarnation on earth.
Further, there is a wonderful promise about this imparted righteousness of God via Jesus given in 2 Cor 5:21 -

God made Him who knew no sin to be sin on our behalf, so that in Him
we might become the righteousness of God.


The Jewish Background
Paul, once a militant Pharisaic Jew, believed in the immutability of the Old Covenant. He thought it was “eternal”. He firmly believed that the “animal sacrifices” really absolved the sins of all the devout Jews. This is why he opposed vehemently the so called new covenant of the Christians which he thought was anti-Scripture.
He never realized at that time that “it is not possible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away sins” (Heb 10:4).
He didn’t know that “the Law, having a shadow of the good things to come, not the very image of the things, by the selfsame sacrifices which they offer continually every year, can never make the comers thereunto perfect” (Heb 10:1).
[It is very clear from the above verse that “the Law” mentioned here is the Law related to the “animal sacrifices” and “foods and drinks, and various washings, and fleshly ordinances”, which were temporarily (shadow) imposed (Heb 9:10)]
These are the works of Law!
Saul didn’t know that these were “added” because of “transgressions” (transgression is breaking of the spiritual law – 1 John 3:4) until Jesus (“the Seed”) came (Gal 3:19).
He was to realize later that the “works of Law” was originally given to the Jewish people “under the Levitical priestly office” (Heb 7:11).
God later revealed to him that when the priestly office was “permanently” changed to “the order of Melchizedek” (Heb 7:11), then:
“For the priestly office having been changed, of necessity a change of law also occurs” (Heb 7:12).
After his conversion, Paul learned that what he thought as the immutable, the first covenant with all its animal sacrifices and fleshly ablutions, was “aging and disappearing” (Heb 8:13).
What Law Mentioned in Romans 3:21
Which Law Paul mentions as “apart”, from which the righteousness of God “has been manifested”?
Let us look at the context:

“Because by works of Law not one of all flesh will be justified
before Him, for through (works of) Law is full ‘knowledge’ (Greek
“epignosis” = recognition/acknowledgement – Strong) of sin. But now a
righteousness of God has been revealed apart from (works of) Law,
being witnessed by “the Law and the Prophets” (the Scripture)”
(Rom 3:20-21).

So, the Law mentioned in Romans 3:21 is the Law of works not the spiritual Law of Ten Commandments.
Works of Law vs. Law of Righteousness
Paul distinguishes between the “works of Law” and the “Law of righteousness” in one and the same passage:

“but Israel following after a Law of righteousness did not arrive
at a Law of righteousness? Why? Because it was not of faith, but
as of works of Law. For they stumbled at the Stone-of-stumbling”
(Rom 9:31-32).

See?
Works of Law is different and separate from the Law of righteousness!
The Law of righteousness is a “goal” to “arrive at”; it is a destination.
But works of Law is a “means” or a process to “arrive at” the Law of righteousness!
Yes, that is what Paul is saying in these verses.
So, the righteousness of God has been manifested apart from the Law of works (or works of Law); but not apart from the Law of righteousness.
The Law of Righteousness
Which law is the Law of righteousness?
Paul says:

“So indeed the Law (the Ten Commandments mentioned in verse 7:1) is
holy, and the commandment holy and just and good” (Rom 7:12).

In the above verse, the word “just” is “dikaios” in Greek which means “righteous”. So the “spiritual” (Rom 7:14) law of Ten Commandments is holy, “righteous” and good.
In Romans 9:31, the Law of righteousness is mentioned. Here, “righteousness” in Greek is “dikaiosunei”.
Thus, we see:
Righteousness = Dikaiosunei
Righteous = Dikaios
Therefore, the Law of righteousness = the Ten Commandments.
The Change in the Second Covenant
Nothing changed in the Second Covenant except that a few things were replaced with better things.
The “shadows” were replaced with the “real heavenly” things!
Animal sacrifices were replaced with a far better “single” sacrifice of the holy Lamb of God, that is, Jesus Christ. This is beautifully presented in Hebrews 10:1-14.
[It is a miracle that God Himself approved Jesus’ sacrifice by removing the Temple in Jerusalem where the animal sacrifices were offered. The Jews cannot sacrifice any animal anywhere except in the Temple in Jerusalem, by Law. They couldn’t sacrifice for nearly 2000 years since 70AD thus validating Jesus' sacrifice]
Circumcision was replaced with baptism.
The political and civil rules were replaced with the Kingdom of God rules.
Faith and Works of Law
The Jews sacrificed animals as propitiation for their sins. They saw everything and ate the roasted flesh of the animals. These are the works of Law in the first covenant.
But this was a shadow of the coming body of Christ. Christ our Passover Lamb was sacrificed “once for all” (Heb 9:26). This really absolved our sins. But we didn’t see Jesus’ sacrifice the same way as the Jews saw the sacrifices of the animals.
Here comes the faith!
It is through faith that we learn that Christ sacrificed Himself for us as a propitiation for our sins.
What was the problem with the Jews? Paul gives a wonderful yet profound answer:

“but Israel following after a Law of righteousness did not arrive at a
Law of righteousness? Why? Because it was not of faith, but as
of works of Law. For they stumbled at the Stone-of-stumbling,
as it has been written, "Behold, I place in" "Zion a
Stone-of-stumbling," "and a Rock-of-offense," "and everyone believing
on Him will not be shamed." (Rom 9:31-33).

Yes, the Jews stumbled at the Stone-of-stumbling which is Jesus Christ. They couldn’t “believe” that Jesus’ sacrifice absolved their sins. They rejected Him. They lacked “faith” in Him.

“For being ignorant of the righteousness of God (through Jesus
Christ), and seeking to establish their own righteousness (through
animal sacrifices or works of Law), they did not submit to the
righteousness of God” (Rom 10:3).


“knowing that a man is not justified by works of the Law (animal
sacrifices), but through faith in (the sacrifice of) Jesus Christ;
even we believed in Jesus Christ, that we might be justified by the
faith in (the sacrifice of) Christ, and not by works of the Law
(animal sacrifices). For all flesh will not be justified by works of
law” (Gal 2:16).

They ate the flesh of the animals they sacrificed. But Jesus Christ said:

“Truly, truly, I say to you, Unless you eat the flesh of the Son
of Man, and drink His blood, you do not have life in yourselves.
Whoever partakes of My flesh and drinks My blood has eternal life, and
I will raise him up at the last day. For My flesh is food indeed, and
My blood is drink indeed. He who partakes of My flesh and drinks My
blood dwells in Me, and I in him” (John 6:53-56).

[The blood of sacrificed animals was to be poured on the ground. Only the flesh was to be eaten. In Jesus’ case nothing, including His blood, was to be left out]
Indeed, the above was possible only through faith! This is why they stumbled at Jesus, the Stone-of-stumbling!
Conclusion
Sin is the transgression of the spiritual Law summarized in the Ten Commandments. The Ten Commandments is the Law of righteousness.
To remove sins, a means was provided by God. This was the perfect and eternal sacrifice of Jesus as a propitiation for the whole world. (As the Creator of all humanity, His one Life was more than enough for the entire humanity).
But before Jesus came, God gave as a shadow – as a reminder of their sins Heb 10:3 – the animal sacrifices in the first covenant. This is called the works of Law. The works of Law involves animal sacrifices. This did not remove the sins of anyone.
Works of Law was replaced in the second and better covenant with Jesus’ sacrifice which really absolved the believers’ sins. But this required faith in Jesus. But the Jews “stumbled” at Jesus.
Answer
Now to answer your question:
What has been manifested?
The righteousness of God imputed to the sinner-believers through the one eternal sacrifice of Jesus Christ (not a shadow but the good heavenly Lamb) has been manifested.
When was it manifested?
At the death and resurrection of Jesus Christ was it manifested.
To whom was it manifested?
To whomever the Gospel was preached.
How was it manifested?
Through hearing of faith was it manifested.
Yes, Jesus came to fulfill "the Law", that is, the Scripture.
The “Law” mentioned in the “apart from Law” in Rom 3:21 is the “Works of Law” contextualized in Rom 3:20.
But the Jews rejected Jesus because God made Him a “Stumbling Block”

"Through hearing of faith" +1

So, you seem to be still under an obligation to keep ten commandments as a necessity of righteousness. (If I have understood you correctly.)

The answer depends on what sin is. The Word says, “Sin is the transgression of the Law” (1 John 3:4). Christ came to save men from sin and God justified the believers freely “from past sins” (2 Pet 1:9). So, one cannot continue in sin (that is, continue breaking the Law). Christ commands, “Sin no more” (John 5:14; 8:11). “So everyone who lives in union with Christ does not continue to sin” (1 John 3:6) because God ‘has written His Law in the hearts and minds of the believers in the New Covenant’ through the Holy Spirit (Heb 8:10; 10:16; 2 Cor 3:3).

“Do not lie to one another, having put off the old man with his practices” (Col 3:9). “Obey your parents in the Lord” (Eph 6:1). “The one stealing, let him steal no more, but rather let him labor” (Eph 4:28). “For whether or not a man is circumcised means nothing; what matters is to obey God's commandments” (1 Cor 7:19). Are these obligations? The true believers at the end of the age still keep “the commandments of God” and “the testimony of Jesus” (Rev 12:17).

The two down votes gave me the courage to ask a counter question: since I am supposed to be not under law but under grace, can I go ahead and do murder, commit physical adultery (yet withstand mental adultery), worship other gods, venerate idols, tell lies, disrespect parents etc. and yet expect myself to end up in the Kingdom of God?
